# Laravel 4 - migration and foregin keys issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, foreign-keys

I want to use migrations for create 2 tables: `users` and `posts`
here it is my code for `create_users_table`:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username',50);
        $table->string('password',100);
    });
```

after that i want to create the `create_posts_table`:

```
Schema::create('posts',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title',100);
        $table->text('content');
        $table->unsignedInteger('users_id');
        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('SET NULL')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and here it is my problem:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
: alter table 'posts' add constraint posts_users_id_foreign foreign key ('u  
sers_id') references 'users' ('id') on delete SET NULL on update CASCADE)
```

I reviewed my code and I found out that I can't add `onDelete('SET NULL')`
why?!How can I make it happens?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I believe `$table->increments()` creates a column just a little bit different from `$table->unsignedInteger()` and for foreign key constraints to be set, the columns must be exactly the same. Try running the migration without the foreign key and see if the columns match up(excluding auto increment).

Comment: beware of my problem mate:
If i delete `onDelete->('SET NULL')` there will be no problem and migrating works

Comment: Have you tried setting your foreign key column to allow null?

Comment: That's it!!!
thanks for your advice,please post your answer to letting me choose your point as a best answer mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference to others having this issue, the fix is simple: allow your foreign key column to be nullable.